# Comparing a character in nasm x86-64 using 64 bit registers

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am new to x86_64 coding and I'm exploring various codes.

I am trying to compare a character 'A' in nasm x86_64 code but the comparison is not equal.

```
; Tests the command line. Similar to a C main function:
;  int main(int argc, char** argv)
;
; - argc, number of args in rdi
; - argv, pointer to pointer in rsi and argv

    global  main
    extern  puts
main:
    mov     rbp, rdi      ; argc in rdi. Save in rbp, caller-saved
    mov     rbx, rsi      ; argv in rsi. Save in rbx, caller-saved
    
    add     rbx, 8
    dec     rbp
    mov     rdi, [rbx]
    cmp     rdi, 'A'
    je      exit1
    call    puts
    mov     rax, 0
    ret

exit1:  
    mov     rax, 1
    ret
```

How can the code be modified to get the desired result?
There are solutions but it uses 8 bit registers as used here [comparing characters in assembly, nasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987212/comparing-characters-in-assembly-nasm), but to clear my basics I wanted to understand why direct comparison such as my code does not work.

Comment: `mov rdi, [rbx]` loads 64 bits, so 8 bytes (characters). That's why it doesn't work. If you want 1 byte, use 8 bit register or zero/sign extend as needed.

Comment: @Jester: Actually, at that point `rbx` holds a `char **`, so one deref gets a `char*`, not 8 characters.  The right fix is `cmp byte [rdi], 'A'`, never holding `char` data in a register.  Of course, a debugger would make this clear.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, it works in that case. Thank you for the brief explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `argv` is a pointer to a list of pointers pointing to null-terminated strings.
  At the top you must dereference the pointer first `mov rbx, [rsi]` so you are actually inspecting the list of `*char` values.
- The size of the `cmp` operands (and in fact for virtually all instructions) matters, quote from Intel’s instruction reference on `cmp`:

  > When an immediate value is used as an operand, it is sign-extended to the length of the first operand.

  You are in fact comparing *two* 64-bit quantities.
- There are (at least) two possible solutions:

  - `cmp dil, 'A'`:
    You can still retrieve 8 Bytes from memory at once, but for comparison purposes you’ll need to specify a partial register.
  - Insert `movsx rdi, dil` before `cmp` (or combined with the fetch in one step `movsx rdi, byte [rbx]`):
    As [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71167053/comparing-a-character-in-nasm-x86-64-using-64-bit-registers#comment125799789_71167053) suggested, you can still perform a 64-bit comparison, but ensure the upper bits are set properly.
- Writing `cmp rdi, 'A'` is an alternative to writing `cmp rdi, 0x41`.
  Upon execution, `0x41` gets sign-extended, so you end up comparing `0x00000041` with the contents of `rdi`.
  *Now*, if you are previously loading *eight* Bytes from `[rbx]`, the upper seven Bytes are *potentially* filled with gibberish or, say, *following* characters from a `char` string.
  This is causing you troubles.
- Side note:
  I’m not sure whether you can call `puts` like that, speaking of parameter passing.
  Isn’t `rdi` supposed to contain *the* *address* of a null-terminated string?

Comment: Calling `puts` is correct because `argv[1]` is a `char*`, not `char` data in RDI at all.  It's doing `if ((uintptr_t)argv[1] == 'A')`.

Comment: I see. Wasn’t it usually `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` anyway? Maybe the comment at the head is misleading in that regard.

Comment: Yes, exactly, main's 2nd arg is `char **argv`, and there's only one deref.  Jester got mixed up.  Try running the program; I did just to double check I wasn't the one missing something :P

Comment: Gosh, right, `argv[]` is essentially `*argv`. [Did I mention I hate C?]

Comment: Yes. I understood the concept now. I Was struggling to figure it out. 
I added 'puts' to check if the 'je' check was correct or not.

Comment: This answer is still not totally correct.  If you start with `mov rbx, [rsi]` (instead of `mov rbx, rsi`?), you'll be looking at characters inside `argv[0]`, the program name.  You actually want `mov rbx, [rsi+8]` to load `argv[1]` into a register.  (@datha).  And if you do add an extra deref, then `puts` wouldn't make sense.  It never makes sense to compare a register value against a character, then pass it as a pointer to `puts`.  In that case `putc` would make sense.